# Kubernetes dashboard through traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a Kubernetes cluster (release 1.23.4) working using Traefik(release 2.7.0).
I would like to access the kubernetes dashboard through IngressRoute Traefix, everything seems to work correctly no error in the log of the Traefik pod and the dashboard but when i want to access the kubernetes dashboard it can not access the page: https://k8sdash.kub.techlabnews.com/api/v1/login/status and I have an error 404.(log in the firefox console).

Use this code for create the IngressRoute :

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: ServersTransport
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-transport
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

spec:
  serverName: "k8sdash.kub.techlabnews.com" 
  insecureSkipVerify: true

---  
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`k8sdash.kub.techlabnews.com`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          port: 443
          name: kubernetes-dashboard
          namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
          serversTransport: kubernetes-dashboard-transport
  tls:
    secretName: kub.techlabnews-com-cert-secret-replica
```

Does anyone have an idea of the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ServersTransport` defined needs to be referred to in the service, hence adding an annotation to the service of Kubernetes dashboard should solve the problem:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.serverstransport: kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-transport@kubernetescrd # The first `kubernetes-dashboard` is the namespace
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Considering that the status code was `404`, there could be other issues with the ingress route. Please check the log of the Traefik pod if the method above does not help.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem - adding an annotation to the Kubernetes dashboard service solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The Secret `kub.techlabnews-com-cert-secret-replica` needs to be defined properly.

I have got same error when forgot to define the secret being used by IngressRoute